# Как сделать свой dataprovider для работы с базой данных

Tags: c#

Есть необходимость сделать своего кастомного провайдера к базе данных. Есть база данных, есть вебсервис, который позволяет делать запросы sql к базе. Можно ли сделать свою реализацию dataprovider, в которой общение с базой будет через  этот вебсервис. Вопрос теоретический и алгоритмический. С чего начать? Принципиальное условие это как раз коннект к базе через веб сервис.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под словом `dataprovider`?

Comment: я имею ввиду класс, который выполняет функции доступа к базе данных через веб сервис.

Comment: В чем тогда заминка? Создайте класс и нужные методы в нем. А что у вас за вебсервис? REST API ?

Comment: есть бд Оракл, есть сервер jboss, который предоставляет web api. К этому веб апи я могу коннектится через функцию типа GetData, функция эта принимает свободный sql запрос и возвращает ответ. И мне нужно как то сделать класс наподобие провайдера типа Ado.net

Comment: Вам не нужно `класс наподобие провайдера типа Ado.net`. Вам нужно реализовать паттерн Хранилище (Repository), в котором будут методы типа `public Task<IEnumerable<Product>  GetProducts()` или `public Task<Product> GetProductByName(string name)`. А внутри этих методов вы и будете использовать `функцию типа GetData` c нужными SQL запросами внутри.

Comment: Спасибо, дельная мысль