# Из чего состоит коннектор к базе данных? Или как поступить

Tags: c#, sql

Можно ли написать свой коннектор к базе данных, можно ли где то посмотреть как он устроен? Есть задача у меня, нужно сделать что то типа своей ОРМ(так как, есть база, но доступ к ней только по http и через функцию, которая переваривает любой sql запрос), вот примеры орм я нашел, но там используются коннекторы к базам уже готовые. Сейчас стою перед выбором, или сделать репозиторий где будут хранится сущности, но там нужен механизм маппинга, а как устроен мапеер я не нашел, или использовать уже готовую простенькую ОРМ, но там нужно писать свой коннектор. Вопросы риторические алгоритмические. 
Доступ к базе происходит через функцию, Getdata(sql запрос), возвращает эта функция массив строк string[]. Обновление базы данных происходит через другую функцию Updatedata(sql запрос, userId,username), возвращает эта функция число int, -1 это ошибка,0 успешно. Сама таблица, из которой я хочу получить сущность выглядит так. Это скрипт самой таблицы

```
   ALTER TABLE KNCHDATA.LABS
 DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE KNCHDATA.LABS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE KNCHDATA.LABS
(
  LABID        NUMBER(3),
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX KNCHDATA.LABS_PK ON KNCHDATA.LABS
(LABID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KNCHDATA.LABIDFILL_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT
ON KNCHDATA.LABS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tmpVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
   tmpVar := 0;

   SELECT lab_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO tmpVar FROM dual;
   :NEW.labID := tmpVar;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END labIDFILL_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KNCHDATA.LABSCHANGED_TRG 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON KNCHDATA.LABS REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
DECLARE
BEGIN
   SetStructuraChanged();

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END LABSCHANGED;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KNCHDATA.LABS_CH_TRG 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON KNCHDATA.LABS REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into tablechangehistory values ('LABS',sysdate,'');
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE;
END LABS_CH_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM KNCHPROD.SYNP_LABS FOR KNCHDATA.LABS;


ALTER TABLE KNCHDATA.LABS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT LABS_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (LABID)
  USING INDEX KNCHDATA.LABS_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

GRANT SELECT ON KNCHDATA.LABS TO KNCHPROD;
```

Если просто, то  это таблица LABS
И в ней есть два поля Это  LABID и DESCRIPTION, вот хотелось сделать механизм, чтобы получить такую сущность.
Понятно что  привожу только одну таблицу для понимания, а так их больше 20 штук. Мне нужно построить механизм (репозиторий), где будут эти сущности на основе таблиц, и минимальный набор команд типа CRUD. Вопросы именно в алгоритме действий, как построить саму логику.
Вот что сделал, получил сущность таблицы, если я правильно понял.

```
 // класс сущность записи в таблице
    public class LABS
    {
        public LABS(String v1, string v2)
        {
        }

        public static string LABID { get; set; }
        public static string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        // в этом методе сопоставляю массив данных с полями класса
        public static LABS CreateFromData(string DataString)
        {
            // парсю строку
            string[] tempSplit = DataString.Split(';');

            return new LABS
            (
              LABID  = tempSplit[0],
              DESCRIPTION = tempSplit[1]
            );

        }


    }

 // получаю данные из базы черз sql запрос
//f это запрос
// collumndelemiter это разделитель, в строке поля разделены между собой ;

   string[] mass = accesweb.getAddData(f, collumndelemiter, false);

            //Создаю сущность таблицы
            List<LABS>TableLABS=new List<LABS>();

            foreach (var VARIABLE in mass)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Добавлю строку в таблицу");
                var instaData = LABS.CreateFromData(VARIABLE);
                TableLABS.Add(instaData);

            }
```

Comment: Смотрю на этот ваш прошлый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/940453/222542), а вы все еще не продвинулись не йоту. В чем заминка то? Вам нужно выводить данные в `datagridview` и потому вам непременно нужен `DataTable` и `ADO.net`? Или что?

Comment: Мне нужно получать сущности из базы данных,  далее передаю их в другой механизм. Главный момент, это механизм получения сущностей, да я должен использовать репозиторий с маппингом, и чтобы мне получить эти сущности, нужно использовать орм, но в моем случае, доступ к базе есть только через веб сервис, через функцию  назовем ее GetData(sql запрос).Потому стандартные орм я использовать не могу, в  орм используется connectionstring (стандартный способ подключения к базе), вот я и думаю как мне организовать доступ данным и сделать механизм организации сущностей и простейший набор функций CRUD

Comment: В каком формате  GetData(sql ) отдает результат? Xml или json или в каком виде?

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать интерфейсы IDbConnection или пронаследоваться от DbConnection. А как это выглядит под капотом можно посмотреть в исходниках https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlConnection.cs

Comment: Функция GetData(sql ) возвращает string[] , то  есть массив строк

Comment: Вам не нужен коннектор к БД, т. к. у вас банально нет доступа к СУБД. Сами же пишете, что у вас доступ к только веб-сервису по http.

Comment: Коннектор действительно не нужен, я имел ввиду реализация самого коннектора как пример для своей реализации подключения к базе.

Comment: По-моему, вам нужен _репозиторий_ (тем более, вы его упоминаете в сообщении). Вот и ищите примеры реализации репозиториев. И примеры мапперов.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример данных, которые возвращает GetData(sql ). И как работает операция обновления данных в БД, используется тоже  GetData(sql ) или какая-то др. функция? Приведите пример сущности, которую вам нужно получить. Я может написал бы вам пример репозитория, если б не приходилось вытягивать из вас, как из пленного партизана, необходимые данные.

Comment: @Bulson Добавил информации

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да по моей логике нужен репозиторий, но возникает вопрос в правильной реализации этой логики,так как в репозитории должен еще и быть маппер, примеры мапперов я видел, но не совсем там очевидные вещи. И сейчас я пытаюсь определить правильный вектор действий

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, кажется вам нужен просто парсер string => ORM Mapper

Comment: @Vfvtnjd а примеры подобного есть в природе, суть в том, чтобы из массива строк сделать зависимости к мапперу? правда тут же возникает вопрос а сохранять данные в базе при таком подходе ?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch я не dev C#, но могу подсказать, посмотреть паттерн Active Record , который с таблицу превращает в коллекцию объектов с методомаи, и.тд. Почитайте про нее

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Спасибо за подсказку,посмотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы не знаете как подступиться к Репозиторию, то рассмотрим такой пример.
Начнем с абстракций. Вот самой общий вид

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    //Queries
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync();
    Task<TEntity> GetAsync(int id);

    //Commands
    Task<int> AddAsync(TEntity entity);
    Task<int> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity);
    Task<int> RemoveAsync(TEntity entity);
}
```

Далее нам понадобится абстракция для соединения с сервером, ее вам, по-видимому, придется доработать под себя.

```
public interface IConnection
{
    string IpAddress { get; }
    string Port { get; }
    string Sid { get; }
    int UserId { get; }
    string UserName { get; }

    //разделитель в строке результата
    char[] Separators { get; }

    //закрытие соединения с сервером
    //возможно понадобится...
    void CloseConnection();

    Task<string[]> GetDataAsync(string sqlRequest);
    Task<int> UpdateDataAsync(string sqlRequest);
}
```

Имея такой класс сущности

```
public class Lab
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

мы можем добавить такую абстракцию

```
public interface ILabRepository : IRepository<Lab>
{
    IConnection Connection { get; }

    //здесь можно добавить объявление необходимых методов
    //актуальных для данной сущности
}
```

Последняя абстракция такая

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
{
    IConnection Connection { get; }
    ILabRepository LabRepository { get; }
    IKnchRepository KnchRepository { get; }
}
```

как видите я добавил еще один интерфейс репозитория `IKnchRepository` к классу фейковой сущности `Knch`. Я сделал это с единственной целью, чтоб вы поняли как действовать с др. сущностями, с которыми вам без сомнения придется работать. Теперь перейдем к конкретике.

```
public class LabRepository : ILabRepository
{
    //ctor
    public LabRepository(IConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connection));
    }

    public IConnection Connection { get; }


    #region IRepository
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Lab>> GetAsync()
    {
        string sql = "select LABID, DESCRIPTION from KNCHDATA.LABS;";
        string[] labStrs = await Connection.GetDataAsync(sql);

        var result = new List<Lab>();
        if (labStrs.Any())
        {
            foreach (var labStr in labStrs)
            {
                string[] strs = labStr.Split(Connection.Separators,
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var lab = new Lab { Id = int.Parse(strs[0]), Description = strs[1] };
                result.Add(lab);
            }
        }

        return result.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public async Task<Lab> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        string sql = $"select LABID, DESCRIPTION from KNCHDATA.LABS where LABID={id};";
        string[] labStrs = await Connection.GetDataAsync(sql);

        var result = new Lab();
        if (labStrs.Any())
        {
            string[] strs = labStrs[0].Split(Connection.Separators,
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            result.Id = int.Parse(strs[0]);
            result.Description = strs[1];
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<int> AddAsync(Lab lab)
    {
        if (lab == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lab));
        if (lab.Id != 0) throw new ArgumentException("Попытка создания новой записи, которая имеет ненулевой Id");

        string sql = $"insert into KNCHDATA.LABS (LABID, DESCRIPTION) " +
            $"values ({lab.Id}, {lab.Description});";

        return await Connection.UpdateDataAsync(sql);
    }

    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(Lab lab)
    {
        if (lab == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lab));
        if (lab.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Попытка обновления записи, которая имеет нулевой Id");

        string sql = $"update KNCHDATA.LABS set DESCRIPTION={lab.Description} " +
            $"where LABID={lab.Id};";

        return await Connection.UpdateDataAsync(sql);
    }

    public async Task<int> RemoveAsync(Lab lab)
    {
        if (lab == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lab));
        if (lab.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Попытка удаления записи, которая имеет нулевой Id");

        string sql = $"delete from KNCHDATA.LABS where LABID={lab.Id};";

        return await Connection.UpdateDataAsync(sql);
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

как видите, здесь вы работаете через создание запросов и передачу их в методы класса реализующего `IConnection` и работу с Oracle сервером.
Класс объединяющий репозитории такой

```
public class DataContext : IDataContext
{
    //ctor
    public DataContext(IConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connection));

        LabRepository = new LabRepository(Connection);
        KnchRepository = new KnchRepository(Connection);
    }

    public IConnection Connection { get; }
    public ILabRepository LabRepository { get; }
    public IKnchRepository KnchRepository { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Connection != null)
        {
            Connection.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Чтоб вы поняли как теперь работать с этим всем счастьем напишем пару тестов. Сначала соорудим чисто тестовый класс реализующий `IConnection`

```
class MockConnection : IConnection
{
    //здесь используется фейковый класс, кот. просто отдает
    //тестовые данные, вам же нужно будет написать свой
    //который будет реально отправлять запросы и получать результаты
    MockOracleServerConnection _oracleServer = new MockOracleServerConnection();

    //ctor
    public MockConnection(string ipAddress, string port,
        string sid, string userName, int userId)
    {
        IpAddress = ipAddress;
        Port = port;
        Sid = sid;
        UserName = userName;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string IpAddress { get; }
    public string Port { get; }
    public string Sid { get; }
    public int UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }

    public char[] Separators => new[] { ';' };


    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        //здесь как бы закрываем соединение
        Debug.WriteLine("Соединение с сервером закрыто");
    }

    public Task<string[]> GetDataAsync(string sqlRequest)
    {
        string[] result = _oracleServer.Getdata(sqlRequest);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public Task<int> UpdateDataAsync(string sqlRequest)
    {
        int result = _oracleServer.Updatedata(sqlRequest, UserId, UserName);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

теперь можно написать тесты, например такие

```
[TestMethod()]
    public async Task GetAllLabs()
    {
        DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(_mockConnection);
        var countRecords = 3;
        var lab = new Lab { Id = 345, Description = "testlab3" };

        IEnumerable<Lab> labs = await dataContext.LabRepository.GetAsync();

        Assert.IsNotNull(labs);
        Assert.AreEqual(countRecords, labs.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(lab.Id, labs.Last().Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(lab.Description, labs.Last().Description);
    }

[TestMethod()]
    public async Task GetLabById()
    {
        DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(_mockConnection);
        var lab = new Lab { Id = 345, Description = "testlab3" };

        Lab resLab = await dataContext.LabRepository.GetAsync(lab.Id);

        Assert.IsNotNull(resLab);
        Assert.AreEqual(lab.Id, resLab.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(lab.Description, resLab.Description);
    }
```

Остальные тесты и проч. можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExRepositoryJBOSS)

Comment: Спасибо, очень грамотно и развернуто, да прибудет с вами сила)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите создать свой коннектор к базе данных чисто для c# - то берёте и пишите его. Структура относительно не сложная. Подключаете `System.Data.Common` и попорядку идем:

1. Создаём factory  `public class myFactory:public DbProviderFactory`
2. Создаём коннектор  `public class myConnection:public DbConnection`
3. Создаём команду `public class myCommand:public DbCommand`
4. Создаём ридер `public class myreader:public IDataReader`

Для "полноценного" драйвера, ещё прийдется наследовать и реализовать `DbParameter` `DbDataAdapter`  и второй очереди: `DbCommandBuilder` `DbDataSourceEnumerator` `DbConnectionStringBuilder` без последних коннектор жить может.

Для написания коннектора - прийдётся обвернуть от 3-х  до 10 абстрактных классов и реализавать около 100 методов. Но... если у БД есть интерфейс Odbc или OleDB  - то лучше к СУБД присоидениться через соответствующие классы. Хотя... наверно можно от одного - создать команду и всё))) всё зависит от того что нужно. Полноценный - около 10. 1)Что бы ускорить написание можно добавлять затычки `throw new NotImplementedException();` (туда где сейчас кусок кода не нужен). Новые версии студии - хорошо сами умеют делать "скелетную реализацию" через рефракторинг- пару кликов в контекстном меню. 2)Я делал ошибку с null, методы интерфейса `IDataReader` а также метод `ExecuteScalar` должны возвращать `DBNull.Value` вместо null. Т.е. там где идет имплементация значения из СУБД то нужно  `DBNull.Value` использовать.

Классы все абстрактные - реализуете абстрактные свойства и методы - и после нескольких дней работы - получаете полноценный коннектор к БД.

Когда коннектор готов - находите у обьекта (например SqlDataSource), который подключается к СУБД свойство - Provider - вписываете туда имя своего провайдера (MyAssembly.myFactory) и всё. Так же можно работать с коннектом напрямую подобно OdbcConnection и SqlConnection.

Если хочется заглянуть на готовое, можно полистать тут http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlConnection.cs хотя это лишь обвертка.. можно вот тут скачать http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9445/Embedded-Firebird-Full-Featured-Embedded-Database как пример, или погуглить коннекторы других баз - и посмотреть их.